# Android Closing My Application Without Any Notification

Tags: android, crash

I am working on Card Scanner application, Using native camera and barcode scanning apis in my app(everything is fine with camera and barcode sanning), also using Spring Android library with Java POJO Objects for in/out to Rest apis.

**ISSUE**
Android is closing my application without any notification, QA reported a bug that he was testing and suddenly app closed(behavior is similar to home button press).

I don't have any idea about this issue. I reproduced this issue at my end and got below mentioned logs in logcat.

Here is my logs:

```
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696): Process: com.ihi.bcr, PID: 25696
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.ihi.bcr.services.ContactSyncService@44e4fbf8 with Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ihi.bcr/.services.ContactSyncService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2719)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.app.IntentService.onStart(IntentService.java:116)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at roboguice.service.RoboIntentService.onStart(RoboIntentService.java:66)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.app.IntentService.onStartCommand(IntentService.java:130)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2702)
01-29 14:35:00.805: E/AndroidRuntime(25696):    ... 10 more
01-29 14:35:00.815: W/ActivityManager(780):   Force finishing activity com.ihi.bcr/.activity.HomeScreen
01-29 14:35:00.975: E/Database(19015): 0
01-29 14:35:01.185: E/Database(19015): 0
01-29 14:35:01.215: D/audio_hw_primary(184): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
01-29 14:35:01.345: W/ActivityManager(780): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4382e1c0 u0 com.ihi.bcr/.activity.HomeScreen t171 f}
01-29 14:35:01.405: E/Database(19015): 0
01-29 14:35:01.645: D/dalvikvm(19015): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 527K, 4% free 17113K/17728K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
```

**NOTE: 
ContactSyncService is intent service.
I am starting contactSyncService by startService() method.**

I didn't override onStart and onStartCommand() functions of IntentService(As it is mention in Android Docs)

Comment: please post `IntentService` and indicate line 116 on that

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan: I didn't override onStart() and onStartCommand() functions in my service. As it is mention at developer.android.com

Comment: OK, just post your code and line 116 on that, you got NPE on that line

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan: bro it isn't at 116th line of my code, exception is at 116th line of android.app.IntentService.onStart(IntentService.java:116) file. Hope you got it. I don't have onStart() function in my service..

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to call super.onCreate() in your ContactSyncService.onCreate().

Comment: i don't overrided onCreate() function?